# dojox.data.JsonRestStore vs dojo.store.JsonRest

Tags: dojo

Can anyone tell me which restStore implementation I should be using? I assumed dojo.store.JsonRest was the correct libarary to use as it's the latest implementation but a collegue said he'd read somewhere (not very helpful I know) that we should still be using dojox.data.JsonRestStore.

Comment: I guess your friend read that here : http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/store/JsonRest.html, at the bottom of the page, in the "misc" paragraph.

Comment: Yes. It must be. "The dojo.store.JsonRest does not provide all the functionality of dojox.data.JsonRestStore itself. Addtional modules and layers are used to provide schema validation, referencing, caching, and other functionality."

Comment: So should I stick with dojo.store if I'm starting from scratch?

Answer (score 4):

dojo.store is the new Dojo datastore interface, introduced in 1.6 and dojo.data is the old interface.

The interfaces are not compatible so if you are working with code or widgets that use the old interface you either need to use the old data store as well or you can try using the dojo.store.DataStore adapter to give the old interface to a new store.

For more information, check the docs: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/store.html

Comment: So if I'm starting a project from scratch I should stick with dojo.store?

Answer (score 0):

JsonRestStore is deprecated now, it is better to stick with JsonRest object now.